# Split a datetime string into date time in C++

Tags: c++, arduino

Assume that I have an string like this: 20160501124254.000

The string is date and time without delimiter. It must be this: 2016/05/01  12:42:54.

How can I split the first string to the second string and save each date and time in separate variables in C++?

Actually I need a little function for it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a code-writing website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like

```
int year;
int month;
int day;
int hour;
int minute;
int second;
sscanf(buffer, "%4d%2d%2d%2d%2d%2d", &year, &month, &day, &hour, &minute, &second);
```